# why does a thread accessing two contiguous elements cause a "bank conflict"?

Tags: cuda, conflict

[image: bank conflict]

As shown in the red box above, I don't understand why a thread accessing two arrays of data consecutively would cause bank conflict, but the following access, as shown below, would not cause conflict.

[image: no bank conflict]

thanks for your answer!!!

Comment: I figured it out, there are some mistakes in the first picture. These threads have the wrong ID,  these threadID should be 0,1,2,3,...... not 0,2,4,6........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/using-shared-memory-cuda-cc/

> **Shared memory bank conflicts**
>
> To achieve high memory bandwidth for concurrent accesses, shared memory is divided into equally sized memory modules (banks) that can be accessed simultaneously. Therefore, any memory load or store of n addresses that spans b distinct memory banks can be serviced simultaneously, yielding an effective bandwidth that is b times as high as the bandwidth of a single bank.
>
> However, if multiple threads’ requested addresses map to the same memory bank, the accesses are serialized. The hardware splits a conflicting memory request into as many separate conflict-free requests as necessary, decreasing the effective bandwidth by a factor equal to the number of colliding memory requests. An exception is the case where all threads in a warp address the same shared memory address, resulting in a broadcast. Devices of compute capability 2.0 and higher have the additional ability to multicast shared memory accesses, meaning that multiple accesses to the same location by any number of threads within a warp are served simultaneously.

Let's assume that there are 8 memory banks of size 4 bytes for your example of parallel reduction. Element i is served by bank i % 8.

Then, banks 0,2,4,6 need to serve two requests in the first example.

In the second example, each bank needs to serve only one request.